# Why does bigquery add points to my linestring geography?

Tags: google-bigquery

Bigquery adds points to my linestring when parsing it and I can't figure out the logic behind it. It's an issue for me because for big lines the number of vertices in the resulting geometry is much bigger and bigquery measure the size of geometry types by number of vertices.

**Example query**

```sql
WITH
  DB AS (
    SELECT 'LINESTRING (-16.71188 28.05526, -16.71172 28.05575, -16.71189 28.05586, -16.71184 28.05528)' as str,
  )
SELECT
  str as original_text,
  ST_ASTEXT(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(str)) AS geog_text,
  ST_NUMPOINTS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(str)) AS geog_n_points,
FROM DB
```

**Output**

```json
[{
  "original_text": "LINESTRING (-16.71188 28.05526, -16.71172 28.05575, -16.71189 28.05586, -16.71184 28.05528)",
  "geog_text":     "LINESTRING(-16.71188 28.05526, -16.7118469906226 28.0553610915993, -16.71172 28.05575, -16.71189 28.05586, -16.7118469906226 28.0553610915993, -16.71184 28.05528)",
  "geog_n_points": "6"
}]
```

The original line has 4 points but the parsed ones ends up with 6. The 2 additional points are the same ones (`-16.7118469906226 28.0553610915993`)

Comment: The added points are line's self-intersection points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Entin provided the answer in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77874149/why-does-bigquery-add-points-to-my-linestring-geography#comment137295165_77874149)

> The added points are line's self-intersection points.